# What are the risks of SSO and logins in general in relation to privacy?

Tags: privacy, sso

I recently started using the Brave browser for a little more privacy.

However, I still don't understand much about the risks surrounding SSO and cookies.

As an example, I am logged in to YouTube.com with my Google account. As an example, if I navigate to google.com, I am also logged in there.

Specifically, I ask myself: What risk does this pose in terms of the risk that my identity could be recognized by third parties?

If I:

1. Navigate to a completely different website: Does this then allow it to see whether and as who I am logged in to Google?
2. Can Google (or the SSO provider in general) read sensitive data (like my browser history)?
3. Is this a problem especially in conjunction with a VPN (whether from Brave or a third-party provider)?

Maybe someone here can clarify these for me.

Comment: 1. does that "completely different website" use Google SSO? 2. Is the SSO provider providing search capabilities? 3. VPNs don't come into this. Unfortunately, you'll need to be a little more detailed in your scenarios. What would help is if you knew how SSO worked.

Comment: 1) If the website is registered with Google, or Facebook, etc... to use their API they can get some information about you.  (Whatever those APIs provide)  Conversely Google and Facebook will know that you visited that site.  2) No.  Browser history is protected from the internet.  3) VPN has no effect.